# How to get a dataurl base 64 encoding from a canvas but only for a sub image?

Tags: html, canvas

I have a canvas, and I want to get a base64 encoding from it to send to server, which I can do with `.toDataURL()`. But the problem is I don't want to send the whole image, I want to send a portion of it. I then have

.getImageData(x, y, w, h) to get the image data of the portion. But now how can I get the data url of this to send to the server?

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a temp canvas and copy the pixels to the canvas then get the data URL of that canvas

```
// context is the context from which to copy
// x,y,w,h is the sub area to copy ar data URL
function getDataURLSubImage(context,x,y,w,h){
    var can = document.createElement("canvas");
    can.width = w;
    can.height = h;
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(context.canvas,-x,-y);
    return can.toDataURL();
}
```

Or if you only have `imageData` you can do the following but it is less efficient than the above method.

```
function imageDataToDataURL(imageData){
    var can = document.createElement("canvas");
    can.width = imageData.width;
    can.height = imageData.height;
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
    return can.toDataURL();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the dataURL can be sent in JSON format.
            $scope.canvasObject = {
                    "screenName" : 'testName',
                    "screenObject" : JSON.stringify(canvas.toDataURL())
                };

In serverside, this will be received in byte array format.

```
    byte[] bytes = null;
    File file = null;
    BufferedImage bfi = null;
    try {
        if (entity != null && entity.getScreenObject() != null) {
            bytes = DatatypeConverter
                    .parseBase64Binary(entity.getScreenObject().replaceAll("data:image/png;base64,", ""));
            file = new File(entity.getScreenName() + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            bfi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            ImageIO.write(bfi, "png", file);
            bfi.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
```

This saves the image in server.